# Alternative Power Source T-800 Terminator 2 Judgement Day

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

From the movie, can it be deciphered, where the alternative power source from the T-800 was located? It does show a schematic on the camera. Any further insight on this?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing useful, I'm afraid. The schematic shows an "Aux Batt" (presumably an Auxiliary Battery) providing "reserve power" but no indication of where it's *actually* located. Given the fact that it's positioned on the blueprint next to a CPU cluster, I'd guess it somewhere inside the head but who the heck knows?

[image]

Oh, and the novelisation is no help either.

Comment: I was curious because, at the last part, when the T-800 is lowered into the molten steel, nothing explodes. Could be the reason that the alternative power source was in a location, with just enough power to kill the T-1000.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - It's an invention of later films that the power cell is explosive.

Comment: But if that were the case, when punctured by the T-1000, why was there so much energy radiating from it? If you take any battery and put fire near it, it will most probably explode. Even in the first film, when the Terminator's upper torso is crushed, there were HUGE electric currents radiating from whatever the power source, within it, was.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - The first terminator's primary power cell was supposedly nuclear. There's no special evidence to suggest it's *explosive* in the presence of fire, though.

Answer (score 2):

"Uncle Bob" used the thermal energy generated by the smelter and accumulated in its internal heat sinks to reboot. A temporary measure to stay "alive", at best, and have a last shot at the T-1000. It worked...

Not actually explained in the movie, but the T2 Extreme DVD text commentary says:

Terminator drew upon the potential energy in his heat sinks to jump start his internal systems since his main power cell was ruptured and discharged by T-1000’s attack"

Source: http://www.jamescamerononline.com/T2FAQ.htm

Comment: Although not untrue, this doesn't answer the question asked (e.g where are they located)

Comment: Funny how I looked at this question and found that it was a really good answer, if I had asked "how". Then I looked back and forgot that I had asked "where". But yes, my question was still "where".